# Is the bowler awarded an extra ball for taking a hat trick?

Tags: rules, cricket

Does the bowler get to bowl an extra ball in the over if he gets a hat trick? If I remember right, this used to be the practice/rule earlier, but probably not so now.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From [Law 22](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-the-over/):

> **1. Number of balls**
>
> The ball shall be bowled from each end alternately in overs of 6 balls.

So only six legal balls are allowed to bowl in an over and no exception is given there. And why should he given extra ball to bowl? I can't see any logic here.

Note: There is no any law for Hat-trick in Cricket laws.

Comment: Absolutely. Also, giving the bowler an extra ball could actually be a bonus to the batsman - it's an extra ball to score off. That wouldn't make sense - why penalise the bowler?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all !

A hattrick is just a fancy informal term to describe 3 wickets taken in 3 consecutive deliveries by a bowler.

And the bowler doesn't get any extra ball for a hattrick !

Answer (score 0):

The bowler may be presented with the ball at the end of the innings, as a trophy for his achievement.

So yes, he would recieve an extra ball - in another sense.